# Is it at all possible for an android device to connect to ps4 as a bluetooth HID keyboard without root?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ps4

I am aware that i could just use the playstation app, but I'm specifically looking to be able to enter an account password remotely without showing the password on the android device ,the app should connect to PS4 (as a bluetooth keyboard i guess), then retrieve the password (from a server for example) and then pass it to PS4,  there are a few open source projects that allow android to emulate a keyboard but they require root.

If this can't work please specify why you think it can't, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for an android device to emulate a bluetooth keyboard without root after the pie-release, but it is not possible to connect to a PS4 without root, because during the bluetooth discovery phase the PS4 is looking for a Mouse or Keyboard. Phones and tablets will be filtered out, and since you can't change the bluetooth class of device (COD) for your android HID bluetooth app it will not be able to connect over bluetooth.